# ADC MCP3421 sample rate problem

Tags: adc, measurement, microchip

I am writing a driver for [mcp3421](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22003e.pdf) ADC IC and I have a problem when I measure in 12-bit accuracy. That is 240 samples per second.

In the datasheet the min and max values are 176 SPS and 328 SPS. So I expect to be able to see a new measurement every:

-min: \$1sec/176 \$ -> \$5,69msec\$

or

-max: \$1sec/328 \$ -> \$3,05msec\$

In reality I poll the mcp3421 every 7 msec to be sure it gets a new measurement but the RDY flag( 0=new measurement ) is set every 50msec.

Is that normal? Why is this happening?

Here is the tree (every 7msec)
[image]

and here is the forest( every 50msec )
[image]

```
 * \brief Reads all mcp3421 registers.
 * 
 * \bug Needs a timeout mechanism or it might hang in a loop if device hardware fails.
 * 
 * It reads mcp3421 and expects either 4 or 3 bytes.
 * If it is in 18-bit all bytes are used.
 * If it is not 18-bit the lower byte is not used.
 * 
 * \param[in,out]   me          The mcp3421 handle.
 * \param[out]      upper       The first byte.
 * \param[out]      middle      The second byte.
 * \param[out]      lower       The third byte(18bit) or configuration byte(12,14,16bit).
 * \param[out]      config_reg  Register is the 3rd byte(12,14,16bit) in row or the 4rth(18bit).
 * 
 * \retval          0           Success.
 * \retval          1           Failed.
 */
static int mcp3421_read_all( mcp3421_t* me, uint8_t* upper, uint8_t* middle, uint8_t* lower, uint8_t* config_reg )
{
    //TODO: Add timeout_ms
    int err = 0;
    do 
    {
        /* Read mcp3421 register */
        uint8_t data[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90 };
        if( i2c_master_receive( &(me->bus), me->address, data, 4U, MCP3421_TIMEOUT ) )
        {
            /* Exit with error */
            errorHandler();
            return 1;
        }

        /* Get data */
        *upper = data[0];
        *middle = data[1];
        *lower = data[2];
        *config_reg = data[3];

        /* Wait until the next read */
        if( mcp3421_delayUntilNextRead( *config_reg ) )
        {
            /* Exit with error */
            errorHandler();
            return 1;
        }

        /* Check if registers are updated */
        if( ( (*config_reg) & RDY_Mask ) == 0 )
        {
            /* Exit with success */
            return 0;
        }
        err++;
    }
    while( err<200 );

    /* Exit with failure */
    errorHandler();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your logic is backwards, #RDY goes low when new data is ready. Post some code if you need more specific help, too many assumption have to be made as is.

Comment: You are right about RDY flag. ( 0=new measurement available ). Changed it in the description.

Comment: Something is not consistent in your description: If your device is in 12-bit mode, you only receive 3 bytes, the last one being the config byte with the ready flag. Yet your code expects 4 bytes. The device returns 4 bytes if it is in 18-bit mode. But then you only get a sample every 250ms. Do you initialize the config register? And if so how?

Comment: Config register is 0x90(default). When in 12/14/16-bit after the third byte you get again the configuration reg. I always get the forth byte in order to have the same code for all sample rates.

Comment: The datasheet says: "If the device is configured for 12, 14, or 16 bit-mode, the device outputs **two** data bytes followed by a configuration byte." (chapter 5.3.3, third paragraph). The documentation of your function `mcp3421_read_all` says the same.

Comment: Yes this is true. In the same paragraph in the very end says: <<The device repeatedly outputs the configuration byte only if the Master sends clocks repeatedly after the data bytes.>> Something that my code does.

Comment: I figured it out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you repeatedly ask for the configuration byte after the data bytes( 2 in the case of 12/14/16bit and 3 in case of 18bit ) the config register is changing. So if your code counts in the last config value acquired you might miss an RDY flag or get a wrong one.

My code did that and it is a bug.

Workaround is asking the correct amount of bytes or the following code.

```
/**
 * \brief Reads all mcp3421 registers.
 * 
 * \bug Needs a timeout mechanism or it might hang in a loop if device hardware fails.
 * 
 * It reads mcp3421 and expects either 4 or 3 bytes.
 * If it is in 18-bit all bytes are used.
 * If it is not 18-bit the lower byte is not used.
 * 
 * In 12/14/16-bit the middle byte is set to zero.
 * 
 * \param[in,out]   me          The mcp3421 handle.
 * \param[out]      upper       The first byte.
 * \param[out]      middle      The second byte.
 * \param[out]      lower       The third byte(18bit) or configuration byte(12,14,16bit).
 * \param[out]      config_reg  Register is the 3rd byte(12,14,16bit) in row or the 4rth(18bit).
 * 
 * \retval          0           Success.
 * \retval          1           Failed.
 */
static int mcp3421_read_all( mcp3421_t* me, uint8_t* upper, uint8_t* middle, uint8_t* lower, uint8_t* config_reg )
{
    //TODO: Add timeout_ms
    uint32_t err = 0;
    do 
    {
        /* Read mcp3421 register */
        uint8_t data[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90 };
        if( i2c_master_receive( &(me->bus), me->address, data, 4U, MCP3421_TIMEOUT ) )
        {
            /* Exit with error */
            errorHandler();
            return 1;
        }

        /* Get data */
        *config_reg = data[3];//This is config for all data rates.
        if( mcp3421_unmarshal_sample_rate( *config_reg ) == mcp3421_sample_rate_18bit )
        {
            /* 18 bit */
            *upper = data[0];
            *middle = data[1];
            *lower = data[2];
            *config_reg = data[3];
        }
        else
        {
            /* 12/14/16 bit */
            *upper = data[0];
            //*middle = 0;
            *lower = data[1];
            *config_reg = data[2];
        }

        /* Check if registers are updated */
        if( ( (*config_reg) & RDY_Mask ) == 0 )
        {
            /* Exit with success */
            return 0;
        }
        err++;
    }
    while( err<1000 );

    /* Exit with failure */
    errorHandler();
    return 1;
}
```